# Should functions that create structs return the struct or a pointer?

Tags: c, memory, design-patterns

I'm learning C and this is one that I can't totally figure out.  I have some code like:

```
typedef struct machine {
  char * name;
} machine;

machine create_machine(char * name)
{
  Machine machine = { .name = name };

  return machine;
}
```

But this means that the machine is on the stack. If the user wants it on the heap they have to create a machine themselves. So I'd need a function like this instead:

```
typedef struct machine {
  char * name;
} machine;

machine * init_machine(Machine * machine, char * name)
{
  machine->name = name;

  return machine;
}
```

The third option is to have `create_machine` create a machine and put it on the heap. Then also have a teardown function:

```
typedef struct machine {
  char * name;
} machine;

machine * create_machine(char * name)
{
  Machine *machine = malloc(sizeof *machine);
  machine->name = name;

  return machine;
}

void machine_teardown(Machine * machine)
{
  free(machine);
}
```

I'm leaning towards the 2nd pattern here. Have a `create_machine` that returns a machine, but then also provide an "init" function that can be called. This gives the consumer the option of putting it either on the stack or the heap.

Does this sound like a reasonable conclusion? What is the pattern that most libraries take here?

Comment: Yes it is reasonable. Second question is not that answerable as it is largely opinions based.

Comment: The answer depends upon the usage, so there is no fixed answer here.

Comment: I would name them `machine_create` and `machine_destroy` so they sort of fit the bill of namespacing in C. If you want the user to be unable to modify `Machine` then I would go for 3, otherwise I would go for 2.

Comment: Opinions are what I'm after here @kaylum. It was my understanding that design patterns are allowed as questions in StackOverflow. I am asking how libraries typically do this kind of thing, so that I conform to common design.

Comment: Opinions based questions are expressly [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Where is the appropriate place to ask design pattern questions then (and why is there a design pattern tag on StackOverflow...)?

Answer (score 2):

They're all reasonable and libraries take all three paths, its a matter of style and application.

Generally for lightweight structures with only a couple of fields, a stack-based approach is used because it avoids the complication of dynamic memory management and the performance hit is minimal.

The second approach of allowing the library consumer to allocate memory is also common when structures grow beyond the nebulous two-to-three field initialization. If the library doesn't need to allocate dynamic memory for its operations this is generally the preferred path.

The final path is extremely common in libraries that have non-trivial operations that will need to allocate dynamic memory in the course of their operations. In this case a mechanism is usually provided for the library consumer define their own memory allocation functions for the library to use. Typically this is done with a macro, but other solutions using function pointers also exist.

It's considered bad form for a library to call the standard `malloc` and `free` functions without providing any opportunity for the consumer application to define how it wants to library to handle dynamic memory.